# Returning the same value type, but with success/failure

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a method..

```
def foo(b: Bar): Try[Bar] = ???
```

`Try` is just a placeholder here. `foo` does something with `Bar`, then returns a value to indicate success/failure. I want to return the original value with the success/failure indication, so when I have a collection, I can know *which* ones failed and succeeded, and do something with them. `Try` doesn't really work for me, because `Failure` wraps an exception (let's say I don't care about the reason why it failed).

I could maybe return `Either[Bar, Bar]`, but it seems redundant to repeat the type parameter.

Are there better alternatives than this?

Comment: Do you want to return the value if it succeeds, or just when it fails?

Comment: You can return (Boolean, Bar)

Comment: for both successes and failures, so I can collect exactly which values succeeded, and which values failed.

Comment: If you need both then you can return `(Bar, Try[Bar])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Either[Bar, Bar]` and `(Boolean, Bar)` are isomorphic and the choice between them is a matter of taste.

I'd personally prefer `Either` because you get a nicer set of operations for mapping over the collection with pattern matching, etc., as well as a `merge` extension method that allows you to write `results.map(_.merge)` to get a `Seq[Bar]` if in some situation you no longer need to make a distinction between successful and failed results. I also find this:

```
val result: Either[Bar, Bar] = foo(input).toOption.toRight(input)
```

A little nicer than:

```
val result: (Boolean, Bar) =
  foo(input).map((true, _)).getOrElse((false, input))
```

Or the alternatives, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Note that to say `Either[Bar, Bar]` and `(Boolean, Bar)` are isomorphic means that you can always convert an instance of either type to the other.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your question: Your solution is almost what you were about to achieve.

```
def foo(b: Bar): Try[Bar] = Try(...)
val succeed = foo(b).getOrElse()
```

In **succeed** you have the value you wanted, or nothing (since you don't care about exception). Very good article is: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html